On the continuity of regular functions

Lemma 3.1 (Hartshorne, p15). A regular function is continuous, when k is identified with $\mathbf{A}^1_k$ in its Zariksi topology.

What does it mean to identify something, and what does it mean for a field to be identified with the affine 1-space over it in the Zariski topology? Why is it essential in order for continuity of $f$?

If your regular map is $f: X\to k$, then to discuss the continuity we need a topology on the image $k$. By identifying $k$ with $\mathbb{A}^1$ we mean that you regard $f$ as a map $f: X\to \mathbb{A}^1$, so now the image inherits the Zariski topology. For the second question, I would say you will learn more by reading the following materials.

Thank you for your answer. I have omitted the second question.
Is the point then that we need to be able to talk about $k$ as a topological space in order to make sense of its closed subsets, and coverings by open sets that enable continuity of a regular function.

@aayad Yes, exactly.
